# getElementById() work in html file but not in js file

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

i cannot find answer to my question in someone else post so here it is:
getElementById return null in java script file (also while testing in console) but work in html file

HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Title</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>

   </head>
   <body>

      <p id="stuff">Some text</p>

   </body>
</html>
```

JS file

```
var title = document.getElementById('stuff');
console.log(title);
title.style.color = "#D4F34A";
```

Comment: Put the `<script>` as the last element of the `<body>`.

Comment: Because when the script runs, the element does not yet exist in the DOM.

Comment: Or add an event listener to trigger the js onready

Comment: @zero298 is it correct to link js file in lat line befor </body>? it works only then

Comment: Use the `DOMContentLoaded` event in your script file to execute the code once it fires, documentation (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)

Comment: @AdamBrinded can you tell me how? i just started learning html, css and js a couple of days ago so i'm not sure how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a callback function for the document event `DOMContentLoaded` event like so, and inside that function do your desired code:

```
//Add this into your script file, and anything you want to have execute once the document
//is fully loaded go inside of the function
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var title = document.getElementById('stuff');
    console.log(title);
    title.style.color = "#D4F34A";
});
```

Comment: it's working, thanks!

Comment: @martyna You're welcome. If you feel this answer is good, please mark it as the accepted answer.